# ¿Es correcto utilizar el verbo ocupar en este contexto?

Tags: sinónimos

Acabo de ver una pregunta en el Stack Overflow español. A continuación viene un fragmento:

> **ocupo** hacer un diseño tipo los círculos de google plus. Que sea un circulo grande contenido por un grupo de círculos pequeños, y **ocupo** que tenga un circulo en medio como si fuera el centro de conjuntos.

Es más: alguien comentó:

> ¿Los círculos que **ocupas** tienen que ser estáticos, dinámicos o como sean?

Obviamente en este contexto `ocupar` parece ser sinónimo de `querer` o `necesitar`.
Mi pregunta es: ¿es correcto utilizar el verbo `ocupar` de esta manera?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pues resulta que sí. Los entresijos del español son inescrutables y el verbo *ocupar* ha adquirido ese significado, a juzgar por lo que dice el *Diccionario de americanismos*:

> **[ocupar](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=ocupar)**.
>
> 1. tr. *Mx, Ho, ES, Ni; Ec, Bo:NE,O, Ch, Ur*, pop + cult → espon. Usar *algo*.
> 2. *Ho, Ni, CR; Mx*, pop. Necesitar *alguien* o *algo* una cosa o a una persona.
> 3. *Ch*. Llevar o vestir una prenda determinada. pop.

Así que sí, en Honduras, Nicaragua, Costa Rica y México se usa como sinónimo de *necesitar*.

Comment: En Colombia no se usa **OCUPAR** para indicar necesidad

Comment: En México no he oído esto.  He oído *ocupar* como sinónimo de *utilizar* (y esto es muy común).

Comment: en el noroeste de Mexico Ocupar se utiliza como sinónimo de "necesitar"

Comment: es el diccionario de Americanismos aceptados por la rae o son considerados regionalismos ?

Comment: @Mike el diccionario de americanismos lo confecciona la ASALE, la asociación de academias de la lengua española de la cual la RAE forma parte. Incluye regionalismos de países concretos y a veces de partes concretas de un país.

Comment: Gracias, @Mike.  Quizás empezó con algo así: "¿Vas a ocupar ese martillo?"  "No, tómalo tú si quieres."

Comment: @aparente001, es lo mismo que yo estaba pensando, hay momentos en los que "ocupar", "usar" y "necesitar" se pueden intercambiar sin que se pierda el significado original de la frase pese a que signifiquen cosas distintas.

Comment: En Jalisco, México siempre se escucha ocupar con el sentido de "necesitar", particularmente en el contexto de cualquier tipo de negocios. Por ejemplo, "Cuántas piezas ocupas?" cuando estoy pidiendo madera, impresiones, lo que sea.